# AWS Genomics Nextflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-batch, nextflow

We follow the workshop as https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-genomics-nextflow-workshop

And follow below 2 cloud formation:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?#/stacks/new?stackName=Nextflow&templateURL=https://s3.amazonaws.com/pwyming-demo-templates/nextflow-workshop/cloud9.cfn.yaml

https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?#/stacks/new?stackName=Nextflow&templateURL=https://s3.amazonaws.com/pwyming-demo-templates/nextflow-workshop/nextflow/nextflow-aio.template.yaml

Followed below steps:

Access IAM User Role with admin privilege / Access root user

Create “VpcStack” template not available error cleared following the second cloud formation template. Successfully created all resources from both cloud formation.

Covered all the points with expected results on Cloud9 Environment Setup: docs/modules/module-0__cloud9-environment.md from GitHub source code.

Verified all the resources created as AWS Resources: docs/modules/module-2__aws-resources.md from GitHub source code. Automatically created all the sources following the second cloud formation template.

Run bash command as “nextflow run hello” from Running Nextflow: docs/modules/module-1__running-nextflow.md from GitHub source code. AWS Batch Jobs started as “Runnable” in AWS Batch Dashboard on the hour. Basically, the AWS Batch job is stuck in RUNNABLE status. (Creating ASG and EC2 instances)

The expected result to complete the workshop followed from GitHub source code and process the .fastq files and get a resuls.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?#/stacks/new?stackName=Nextflow&templateURL=https://s3.amazonaws.com/pwyming-demo-templates/nextflow-workshop/nextflow/nextflow-aio.template.yaml
Problem Statement: After creating all resource and followed all processes, We tried to Run bash command as “nextflow run hello” in Cloud9 Studio from GitHub source code (docs/modules/module-1__running-nextflow.md). AWS Batch Jobs started as “Runnable” in AWS Batch Dashboard but it is not moving to "Running" State.

Comment: Can you describe your computing environment / queue settings? I keep getting similar issues when running own pipelines (nf-core/mag). It is stuck forever when I select manually allowed instance types (according to expected CPU/MEM), no matter on provisioning method (best fit progressive, spot capacity..). It is working with "optimal" instance types, just EC2 instances that are provisioned are super huge and seems underutilized most of the time.

Comment: Actually I followed the workshop and while trying to run HelloWorld, encountered the exact same problem: jobs stuck as RUNNABLE.

Answer (score 1):

The workshop content you are using is >4yrs old. It is out of date and will be removed shortly to avoid further confusion. To run Nextflow with AWS Batch, I suggest following more recent guidance published by [Seqera Labs](https://seqera.io/) who maintain both open source and commercial versions of Nextflow:

https://seqera.io/blog/nextflow-and-aws-batch-inside-the-integration-part-1-of-3/